# Is there a physically-based model for atmospheric perspective color?

Tags: optics, visible-light

In the picture below, mountains farther away blends into the color of sky, this is "atmospheric perspective", caused by atmospheric scattering. This effect is also called "fog".

[image: Distant mountains]

But dark blue appears in the middle of the [green -> light blue] gradient somehow. Why? Is there a physically-based model to explain that?

In many video games, they used linear gradient to simulate the fog. The color what we see is a linear interpolation between the color of the object and the color of sky. It looks like the gradient in the right side of the picture. But that isn't realistic because of the missing "dark blue" color, so mountains in video games usually looks too grey.

My guess: The dark blue color is caused by Rayleigh scattering. The white color at the farthest mountain is caused by Mie scattering. Somehow combine them makes the fog both blue and white. But I have no idea how.